# What's wrong with my JavaScript? (C#/ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onholdev(index) {
    var chk = document.getElementById('<%=grdCons.Rows[' + index + '].FindControl("chkHold").ClientID %>');
    var txt = document.getElementById('<%=grdCons.Rows[' + index + '].FindControl("txtReason").ClientID %>');


    if (chk.checked == true) {
        txt.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        txt.disabled = true;
        txt.value = "";
    }
}
</script>
```

The 'index' variable comes from the RowDataBound event of my GridView, like so:

```
  CheckBox chkHold = ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkHold"));
  chkHold.Attributes.Add("onchange", "onholdev(" + e.Row.RowIndex + ")");
```

However, I'm getting 'too many characters in string literal' in the first line of my function (beginning with var chk). Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing client and server-side script...you just can't do this.  This is executed server-side:

```
grdCons.Rows[' + index + '].FindControl("chkHold").ClientID
```

But you're calling it client-side and trying to pass an ID, that's just not something you can do, look at your rendered JavaScript function and this will be much clearer.  Instead just use the ID of the table, then you can find your controls that way, for example:

```
var row = document.getElementById("grdCons").rows[index];
var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName("input");
//then filter by ID match, class, whatever's easiest and set what you need here
```

Comment: That's not strictly true - He's using server-side to output the client Id of a control which is pretty much the only way to get the Id as ASP.Net generates them semi-randomly. The generated javascript should look something like: `var chk = document.getElementById('chk_0000001');`. That said, I agree it's better to try and stay all server side if you can

Comment: @Basiclife - That's not correct, look at the function, `index` is a parameter that gets passed in, this would have JavaScript trying to access a server-side collection (`grdCons.Rows`) by index, you simply can't do this.

Comment: Ah - I hadn't spotted that he was using a JS index in the call. Yeah that's never going to work :)

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because ASP.NET throws an error, which is written in the client side call of `getElementById`. The `onholdev` function is executed client - side, and so cannot pass the index parameter to ASP.NET which is executed server - side. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onholdev(checkbox, textbox) {
    var chk = document.getElementById(checkbox);
    var txt = document.getElementById(textbox);

    if (chk.checked == true) {
        txt.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        txt.disabled = true;
        txt.value = "";
    }
}
</script>
```

Replacing your server - side code with this:

```
CheckBox chkHold = ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkHold"));
chkHold.Attributes.Add("onchange", "onholdev('" + 
    e.Row.FindControl("chkHold").ClientID + "','" + 
    e.Row.FindControl("txtReason").ClientID + "')");
```

Comment: +1 - definitely another viable solution...I'd *personally* go the unobtrusive route, but in webforms the page is littered with inline script anyway...

Comment: I know (sigh), and I've got some issues with that currently. It sucks big time mixing the two... :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of the single quote characters in `' + index + '`. Change those to double qoutes and it should work.

Comment: This isn't the issue, I mean syntactically yes, but if you step back and look at what he's doing, this won't really solve it :)

Comment: No it shouldn't. *index* is a variable within the javascript function. This will never work, and `Rows[]` expects an integer, not the string `" + index + "`.

Comment: @David - Not even that, this is a **client side** function, JavaScript, you can't access a server-side collection like this in the first place.

Comment: @Nick: Hmm, that's what I was getting at (my response wasn't aimed at you, btw, your comment wasn't there when I started typing it). Sorry if I wasn't being very clear. What I meant to say was that implementing the change Krof suggests would be passing `" + index + "`, rather than an integer, to `Rows[]`, which would just plain not work.